# stack() takes very long for large multiindex dataframes

Tags: stack

I have a pandas dataframe of the size 100 x 100000 with both index and columns being multiindex. `df.stack([col1, col2, ..., col5])` would take up to 20 minutes. Sometimes the process gets killed, if there is something else running in the background and not enough resources are available. The goal is to cast the wide-format dataframe into a long-format dataframe.

Is there a way to speed this up?

I haven't had a good idea of what to try yet, maybe splitting the df into n smaller dataframes and stack them in parallel?